# How to get DF from XML using read_xml() and xpath?

Tags: xpath, readxml, local-name

> Here is a XML with various values as follows. How can I parse each
> value?

```
df = pd.read_xml(StringIO(r.text), xpath='//*[local-name()="result"]')
```

> This shows:    RGT_STD_DT  CASH_ALOC_RATIO  ISSUCO_CUSTNO  RGT_RACD 0
> NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN 1         NaN        NaN
> NaN        NaN 2         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN 3
> NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN 4         NaN        NaN
> NaN        NaN 5         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN 6
> NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN 7         NaN        NaN
> NaN        NaN 8         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN 9
> NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vector result="10">
  <data vectorkey="0" type="Document">
    <result>
      <RGT_STD_DT value="20231005"/>
      <CASH_ALOC_RATIO value="220"/>
      <ISSUCO_CUSTNO value="997"/>
      <RGT_RACD value="103"/>
    </result>
  </data>
</vector>
```

> Could you please hele me to get each value under "result"?

Comment: Here is a XML with various values as follows.
How can I parse each value?

df = pd.read_xml(StringIO(r.text), xpath='//*[local-name()="result"]')
This shows:
   RGT_STD_DT  CASH_ALOC_RATIO  ISSUCO_CUSTNO  RGT_RACD
0         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
1         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN

**"My XML"**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<vector result="10">
    <data vectorkey="0" type="Document">
        <result><RGT_STD_DT value="20231005"/><CASH_ALOC_RATIO value="220"/><ISSUCO_CUSTNO value="997"/><RGT_RACD value="103"/></result>
    </data>
</vector>

Comment: I don't think this can be done with `read_xml()`; you should use first lxml and then convert to a df.

Answer (score 1):

Values are stored in attributes not on element's text.
For the given sample: read all attributes, transpose the frame, and give each column the element name

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

xml='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vector result="10">
  <data vectorkey="0" type="Document">
    <result>
      <RGT_STD_DT value="20231005"/>
      <CASH_ALOC_RATIO value="220"/>
      <ISSUCO_CUSTNO value="997"/>
      <RGT_RACD value="103"/>
    </result>
  </data>
</vector>'''

df = pd.read_xml(StringIO(xml), xpath='//*[local-name()="result"]/*')
df2 = df.transpose()
print(df2)
df2.columns = ["RGT_STD_DT" ,"CASH_ALOC_RATIO", "ISSUCO_CUSTNO", "RGT_RACD"] 
print(df2)
```

Transposed frame

```
              0    1    2    3
value  20231005  220  997  103
```

Final result with column names

```
       RGT_STD_DT  CASH_ALOC_RATIO  ISSUCO_CUSTNO  RGT_RACD
value    20231005              220            997       103
```

if more that 1 result element is present use

```
i=0
df2 = []
while i < len(df.index):
    tdf = df[i:i+4]
    tdf = tdf.transpose()
    tdf.columns = ["RGT_STD_DT" ,"CASH_ALOC_RATIO", "ISSUCO_CUSTNO", "RGT_RACD"]
    df2.append(tdf)
    i=i+4

print(pd.concat(df2))
```

Result

```
       RGT_STD_DT  CASH_ALOC_RATIO  ISSUCO_CUSTNO  RGT_RACD
value    20231005              220            997       103
value    20231105              339            768        97
```

### Using Pandas 2.1.1

This version has much better handling of NaNs or NaTs

```
df = pd.read_xml(StringIO(xml), xpath='//*[local-name()="result"]/*', attrs_only=True)

i=0
df2 = []
while i < len(df.index):
    tdf = df[i:i+4]
    tdf = tdf.transpose()
    tdf.columns = ["RGT_STD_DT", "TH1_PAY_TERM_BEGIN_DT", "SHOTN_ISIN", "ISSUCO_CUSTNO"]
    tdf['RGT_STD_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(tdf['RGT_STD_DT'], format='%Y%m%d')
    tdf['TH1_PAY_TERM_BEGIN_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(tdf['TH1_PAY_TERM_BEGIN_DT'], format='%Y%m%d')
    df2.append(tdf)
    i=i+4
    

print(pd.concat(df2))
```

Result
NaN now appears as NaT since dates are parsed.
`value=""` would produce a NaT

```
      RGT_STD_DT TH1_PAY_TERM_BEGIN_DT  SHOTN_ISIN  ISSUCO_CUSTNO
value 2023-11-01                   NaT    183190.0        21505.0
value 2023-10-31                   NaT    448730.0        48052.0
value 2023-10-31                   NaT    453440.0        48543.0
value 2023-10-05            2023-10-25      9970.0          997.0
value 2023-10-04            2023-10-18     78520.0         9602.0
```

Comment: Thanks so much LMC. Here is another question to handle NaN. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77408340/how-to-get-df-from-xml-using-read-xml-and-xpath2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The best way to say "Thanks" here is to accept and/or upvote the answer ;-)